# Setting Ember Data properties on custom DS.Attr types - Or refreshing the template view

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

This has been the cause of endless pain for me, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. First Ember.JS project I've worked on.

Essentially I have a bunch of 'Question' models. Basically the boiled down version is:

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  answers: DS.attr('array'),
  chosen_answers: DS.attr('array'),
});
```

Answers is an array. Since there is no DS.attr('array') by default, I've defined it by:

```
/* Register 'array' data type */
DS.ArrayTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return (Ember.typeOf(serialized) == "array")
        ? serialized 
        : [];
  },
  serialize: function(deserialized) {
  var type = Ember.typeOf(deserialized);
    if (type == 'array') {
        return deserialized
    } else if (type == 'string') {
        return deserialized.split(',').map(function(item) {
            return jQuery.trim(item);
        });
    } else {
        return [];
    }
  }
});
App.register("transform:array", DS.ArrayTransform);
```

Anyway the answers array is populated to be an associative array of (the important bits..) (title, is_active). is_active is set to true, when that answer has been selected.

So the question model holds an array of answers. In my template, when I click on one of the answers presented I fire off an action to the QuestionController. In that action, I want to be able to do:

```
this.set('answers[0].is_active', true);
```

(Obviously replacing the '0' with the correct index, but that's not important for this question).

The closest I believe I've come is:

```
var answers = this.get('answers');
answers[0].is_active = true;
this.set('answers', answers);
```

However this doesn't update the {{#if this.is_active}} handlebars helper I have in the template. 
Weirdly, if I fire off the action, navigate 'back', then navigate 'forward', the {{#if this.is_active}} helper renders correctly.

This has had me totally stumped for days. Any pointers would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably tripping up because you're setting a property not using Ember's `get`/`set`, if you just set it using foo.property Ember has no way of capturing the fact that the property has changed.  Since I'm guessing answer itself isn't an Ember Object, you can still use `Ember.set(obj, 'property', value)` and any observers watching will be notified the property has changed.

```
var answers = this.get('answers'),
    answer = answers.objectAt(0);

Ember.set(answer, 'is_active', true);
```

Comment: Wiping away tears of happiness right now.

Thank you!!